# How to get the position of a selected option in a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I use jquery to find the position of the currently selected option, it also needs to update in real time if the user selects a different option.

```
 <select id="visa_type_c" title="" name="visa_type_c">
     <option selected="selected" value="No Visa" label="No Visa">No Visa</option>
     <option value="EU Visa" label="EU Visa">EU Visa</option>
     <option value="Easy Visa" label="Easy Visa">Easy Visa</option>
     <option value="Hard Visa" label="Hard Visa">Hard Visa</option>
 </select>
```

I seen the other threads but they are slightly different and I cant seem to make it work right for me.

Comment: Show us the jQuery you've already tried

Comment: Did i understand, `Hard Visa` will be on the `4th` position ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Get selected option from dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380230/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Comment: M1K10: Positions should be 0,1,2,3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$("select").on("change", function(ev) {
    console.log(ev.target.selectedIndex);
});
```

Comment: This is more or less all I needed!

Answer (score 8):

Can just use pure JS:

```
document.getElementById("visa_type_c").onchange = function() {
    alert(this.selectedIndex);
}
```

Pure JS Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Xxqnr/1/

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href='javascript:alert($("#visa_type_c option:selected").index())';>click for index</a>
```

Lots of ways to do it; if you add this to your page it will show you the selected index.