# How to move the value of the "SELECT BOX" into text box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is not working can u please help me out.
i want the value ofsome name
i.e helloooooooooo to be printed within textbox

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
          $(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
              $("#name").val();
          }
      //]]>
      </script>
      <title>Task List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="https://kanbanflow.com/api/v1/tasks?apiToken=024b427a5d41a62edd218bddb55ed1fc">
        <select>
          <option value="258f2200948711507b78fb18a9a7">To-do</option>
          <option value="258f2202948711e3b45079a7">In progress</option>
          <option value="258f2201948711e3b4507b788a9a7">Do today</option>
          <option value="258f2203948711e3b4507fb18a9a7" selected="selected">Done</option>
        </select> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />
        Name :<input type="text" name="name" id="name" /><br />
        Color :<input type="text" name="color" /><br />
        Description :<input type="text" name="description" /><br />
        <button id="button" value="submit">create_task</button>
      </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Will you ask a question each 15 minutes without firstly trying to resolve your own issue by yourself?!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380230/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown

Comment: @ A. Wolff. if u can answer i would be glad to receive your response else thanks. i ll look for someone else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign onchange select box value to the inbox

Try like this

```
$(document).on( 'change', 'select', function () {
    $("#name").val($(this).val());
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/na8qL/125/)</kbd>

If you want selected option text

```
$(document).on( 'change', 'select', function () {
    $("#name").val($(this).find('option:selected').text());
});
```

<kbd>[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/na8qL/126/)</kbd>

Comment: It looks like he wants to print the selected element text. `$(this).find('option :selected').text()`