# How can I get selected list attributes in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wan't this alert box to show the attribute `item_name` when the button is clicked. I have JQuery.

Here is the code i'm trying to use it dosn't work though

**HTML**

```
<select class="p1add1">
    <option class="op1" value="3.74" item_name='BOWL'>Bowl   - £3.74</option>
    <option class="op2" value="7.53" item_name='COSTER'>Coster - £7.53 (six pack)</option>
    <option class="op3" value="5" item_name='CLOCK'>Clock  - £5.00</option>
</select>
<input type='button' value="Go!" id='bu' />
```

**JQuery**

```
$('#bu').click(function() {
    alert($('.p1add1').attr('item_name'));
});
```

JSfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/LYv2W/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Get selected option from dropdown](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380230/jquery-get-selected-option-from-dropdown)

Comment: You want to get the attribute for *all* of the `<option>` elements, or just from the *selected* `<option>` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#bu').click(function() {
    alert($('.p1add1').children('option:selected').attr('item_name'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LYv2W/1/

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
alert($('.p1add1 :selected').attr("item_name"));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LYv2W/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the attribute from the selected `<option>`:

```
$('#bu').click(function() {
    alert($('.p1add1 option:selected').attr('item_name'));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LYv2W/2/).

If you want to get *all* the attributes:

```
$('#bu').click(function() {
    alert($('.p1add1 option').map(function(){
        return this.getAttribute('item_name');
    }).get().join(', '));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LYv2W/3/).

Though if you want to use custom attributes, and would like your document to validate (assuming you're using html 5), I'd strongly advise using `data-*` attributes instead:

```
<select class="p1add1">
    <option class="op1" value="3.74" data-item_name='BOWL'>Bowl   - £3.74</option>
    <option class="op2" value="7.53" data-item_name='COSTER'>Coster - £7.53 (six pack)</option>
    <option class="op3" value="5" data-item_name='CLOCK'>Clock  - £5.00</option>
</select>
<input type='button' value="Go!" id='bu' />
```

With the jQuery:

```
$('#bu').click(function() {
    alert($('.p1add1 option:selected').data('item_name'));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LYv2W/5/).

References:

- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/).
- [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).
- [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).
- [`:selected` selector](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/).